# SPFx web part with CDS

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, spfx

I am looking for help to create SPFX web part where I want to access CDS entities and perform below actions

1. Retrieve entity records
2. Add record
3. Update record
4. Delete a record

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/overview) web services to get CDS data.

For authentication an Azure AD app will need to be registered like mentioned in [this documentation article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory).

And for executing the api calls from the SPFx web part the AADHttpClient library can be used like mentioned in [this documentation article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi#consume-the-enterprise-api-secured-with-azure-ad-from-the-sharepoint-framework).